# Questions frequently routed to the "robot detector" which fails on Safari

Tags: bug, api, captcha

My preferred browser is Safari.  Sometimes, I post a question and get the CAPTCHA because "we're not sure you're human."  Unfortunately, on this website, as on more than ten percent of sites I visit, the CAPTCHA is broken, and stays busy until I get tired of waiting and kill it.  I then copy the text, go to Firefox, paste it in, post, and no CAPTCHA appears.

This may be a bug in Safari, but I've read that it is caused by a code change at Google that requires a corresponding change in the client webserver.  I have no proof this is true, but I do know it started about a year ago.

I've never tried SE on the DuckDuckGo browser, but when I tried another site with this problem, DuckDuckGo reported a timeout while Safari was still showing the "busy" cursor.

Comment: What operating system you have? Are you on a mobile device? Anyway this appears to be issue with the Capthca itself which isn't part of SE and not SE "fault". If you find the "code change at Google that requires a corresponding change in the client webserver" you can start feature request asking SE to make that change.

Comment: Testing the captcha on my mac with safari works for me. Do you have any adblockers enabled by any chance?

Comment: Nothing callig itself an ad-blocker, but I suppose the DuckDuckGo privacy extension is similar.  Yet, if it happens on some websites and not others when the _look_ of the CAPTCHA is the same, there must also be something on the website that affects whether it happens or not.

Comment: @WGroleau I think I heard from another meta post that the DDG extension causes some sort of problem with SE. What happens with it disabled?

Comment: I'll have to try that.  If that's the culprit, it causes the same problem with a lot of websites.  For _some_ of those, Firefox works fine and others don't even display the CAPTCHA.  And for the one or two I tried on the DDG browser, clicking the CAPTCHA gets a time-out in a minute or two.